# Оценить учебный проект для решения задачек

Tags: java, проектирование

Немного начал изучать программирование, выбрал Java, поскольку применяется на работе.

Нашёл сайт с задачками по программированию для обучения. Суть в том, что есть пул заданий по номерам. Сайт даёт какие-то входные данные в несколько строк, а с этими входными данными нужно что-то сделать и выдать строчку результата.

Мне показалось скучным просто решать эти задачки (по классу на каждое) и решил себя немного попробовать в проектировании приложений.

Прошу оценить выбранный подход к проектированию. Насколько он хороший, может что-то лучше переделать, какие недостатки видно? Что наоборот хорошо придумано? Проект небольшой - только учусь. Если интересно - есть рабочий исходник.

**Задумка следующая:**

1. Вас спрашивают id задания с сайта;
2. Предлагают ввести (скопировать с сайта) строчки с входными данными;
3. Решается задачка, выводится ответ.

**Собственно, что у меня получилось:**

1. В отдельном пакете есть абстрактный класс Solution и у него есть наследники (сами решения задания).
2. Есть отдельный класс Task, который в зависимости от того, какой id задания введён создаёт объект нужного класса и отдаёт ссылку типа Solution.
3. Есть отдельный класс Interface, который обеспечивает вывод в консоль и парсинг входных данных в массив, который нужен классу Solution, чтобы с ним оперировать. Класс временный, пока не добрался до изучения GUI.

Далее описание самих классов:

**1. abstract public class Solution**

```
int taskId - ID задания
String taskName, taskDesc - наименование и описание задания
String firstLineRegExp, regExp - регулярные выражения на основание которых проверяется корректность ввода первой строки и остальных
String answer - генерируемый ответ
boolean firstLineUni - указатель на то, первая строка уникальная или такая же, как все остальные
ArrayList<String> inArray - входные данные
```

У класса есть 2 конструктора:

а) один принимает и устанавливает taskId, taskName, taskDesc, regExp

б) другой принимает и устанавливает taskId, taskName, taskDesc, regExp, firstLineRegExp

В зависимости от конструктора, в нём автоматически задаётся значение firstLineUni (false, true).

Методы:

```
setInArray() - задаём входной массив с которым будем оперировать

getTaskId(), getTaskName(), getTaskDesc(), getTaskDesc(), getInArray(), getAnswer() - считываем переменные из объекта

checkArray() throws Exception - в зависимости от firstLineUni проверяем входные данные. Если некорректны по регулярному выражению - возвращаем Exception с сообщением.

abstract makeSolution() - реализуется только у наследников, оперируя с inArray в конце выставляем значение answer.
```

Наследники:

а) Реализуют каждый свой конструктор (в зависимости от того, уникальная ли первая строка входных данных), но всегда вызывается конструктор super();

б) Если нужно, переопределяют checkArray(), выполняют super.checkArray(), а потом дописываются свои проверки под конкретное задание.

в) Реализуют makeSolution()

**2. public class Task**

Имеет только один метод

```
public Solution newTask(int id) throws Exception
```

Он создаёт ссылку с типом Solution.
В зависимости от принятого id он этой ссылке присваивает новый создаваемый объект нужного класса (который наследник Solution), а в конструктор передаёт id, название, описание заданий. Метод возвращает ссылку на новый объект.

Может быть Exception, что введённого id несуществует.

**3. public class Interface**

Осуществляет вывод сообщений в консоль и запрос данных для задания. Поскольку в консоль ввод только построчный, то запрос данных я реализовал через *задний проход* - создаю файл, жду пока его сохранят (прошу нажать Enter), а затем построчно читаю этот файл.

Методы:

```
generateFile() throws Exception - создаем файл

openFile() throws Exception - открываем файл

checkFile() throws Exception - проверяем файл, что не пустой

ArrayList<String> parseFile() throws Exception - считываем строки файла в массив с удалением начальных/конечных пробелов и дублированием пробелов между данными

start() - запуск всего
```

Логика start():

а) Открываем цикл (чтобы выполнение задания повторялось)

б) Открываем try

в) Просим ввести id задания и передаем его в Task, который вернёт нам ссылку на задание с заполненными id, name и т.д.

г) Печатаем собственно задание на экран

д) Создаём и открываем файл, просим нажать Enter когда сохранят файл

е) Затем файл проверяем и парсим в массив, который передаём по ссылке в объект класса Solution

ё) Выводим на экран то что ввели, но отформатированное

ж) Проверяем массив методом из Solution

з) Обращаемся к Solution, чтобы он посчитал все данные

и) Забираем ответ и печатаем его

й) Закрываем try, в catch мы выводим на экран сообщение из Exception

к) Спрашиваем, повторить ли выполнение программы

Comment: OFFTOP. В Java методы начинаются с маленькой буквы.

Comment: Спасибо, названия методов исправил